# Can you use a code compiler to merge HTML components?

Tags: php, html, compilation, precompile

**Little context:**.
I've started using [Codekit (macOS)](https://codekitapp.com) to compile my SASS code quickly. It's an amazing application, but it has me wondering about HTML compiling. I've got a client on a separate project that often changes the content of a component (including the navigation..). This change affects many pages and since the website is written in plain HTML, instead of (i.e.) a Wordpress framework, the adjustment has to be made on every .html file. To ease my task, I've converted the files to .php so I was able to use the PHP `import` functionality to import each frequently changing component from an external file. Now I only have to edit that file.

**My question:** Is there a compiling application that can merge/import multiple HTML files in a specific order/location on the file? This way I can stop using PHP's import function and remain relying on HTML files.

---

<sup>*Perhaps an odd question where the only answer may be simply 'No, not possible'. In that case, please say so instead of closing.*</sup>

Comment: By `import` I'm sure you mean either `include` or `require`. Technically, PHP is the compiling language you are actually asking for. Can you give an example why you want to remove away from PHP?

Comment: I exactly mean include. I'll edit that right away. But even if the PHP functionality is as little as that, it still requires some overhead which I'm trying to avoid. I want to compile them before uploading, instead of compiling when requested by the user.

Comment: If it's an option to pass the overhead to the user rather than the server, then you can use javascript to achieve this. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp